# Why digital pin not reading ON from push button switches connected to 5V and pull-down 10K resistor?

Tags: arduino-uno, digital, switch

Here's my circuit: 
[image]

And the code:

```
//pins
const int control1 = 2;
const int control2 = 3; 
const int enable = 9; 
const int pinDirection = 4; 
const int pinOnOff = 5;
const int pot = A0; 
//states
int stateOnOff = 0;
int stateOnOffPrev = 0;
int stateDirection = 0;
int stateDirectionPrev = 0;

int motorEnabled = 0;
int motorSpeed = 0;
int motorDirection = 1;

void setup(){
  pinMode(pinDirection, INPUT);
  pinMode(pinOnOff, INPUT);
  pinMode(control1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(control2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enable, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(enable, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  stateOnOff = digitalRead(pinOnOff); 
  delay(10);
  stateDirection = digitalRead(pinDirection);
  motorSpeed = analogRead(pot)/4;

  if(stateOnOff != stateOnOffPrev){
    if(stateOnOff == HIGH){
      motorEnabled = !motorEnabled;
    }
  }

  if(stateDirection != stateDirectionPrev){
    if(stateDirection == HIGH){
      motorDirection = !motorDirection;
    }
  }
Serial.println(stateDirection);  
  if(motorDirection == 1){
    digitalWrite(control1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(control2, LOW);
  }else{
    digitalWrite(control1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(control2, HIGH);
  }

  if(motorEnabled == 1){
    analogWrite(enable, motorSpeed);
  }else{
    analogWrite(enable, 0);
  }

  stateDirectionPrev = stateDirection;
  stateOnOffPrev = stateOnOff;

}
```

As you can see, the switch on pin 5 controls whether the motor is on and the potentiometer controls motor speed. Both work.

However, when the switch on pin 4 is closed the `stateDirection` variable still reads 0, or open circuit. It should when pressed change the direction of the motor via the H-bridge. I've tried everything I could, new switches, higher resistance. The only time it read HIGH is when I literally plugged switch out to GND.

Serial shows `stateDirection` as an unending chain of zeroes.

And finally the schematics from the original project. 
[image: schematics]

Thank you.

**PS: Forgive for lack of comments! But I think a good Arduino programmer should not need comments. **

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57189/discussion-on-question-by-roman-why-digital-pin-not-reading-on-from-push-button).

Comment: What if you use an empty breadboard and put in a button and resistor only? And make your code print the button state over and over?

Answer (score 1):

> when the switch on pin 4 is closed the stateDirection variable still reads 0, or open circuit.

you could have pull-up enabled on that pin: with a nominal value of 50k, 10k pull-down is just on the cusp of making it a logic low.

solution?

1) disable pull-up;
2) use a stronger pull-down;
3) get rid of the pull-down and rely on the pull-up alone.
...

Answer (score 1):

If it shows low when bypassing switch and jumping to ground.. Then either bad switch or maybe simply wrong orientation of switch.

Edit: if GND is making pin 5 HIGH in logic, then your button needs to jump to GND and have the resistor on 5v. Currently it is opposite according to your schematic.